# How to update only some properties of object in MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

My code below doesn't allow the API user to update only one field by passing one request property. I can remove the null at `userObj`, but the UI developer will have to pass existing data from the database to do an update, which is not the best practice.

Here is my Express route:

```
router.put('/user', (req, res) => {
  const userObj = {
    name: req.body.name || null,
    location: {
      city: req.body.city || null
      },
      phone: req.body.phone || null
    };

  User.updateUser(req.body.id, userObj)
});
```

Here is my Mongoose model's `updateUser` function:

```
module.exports.updateUser = (_id, userObj, callback) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, userObj, { upsert: true, 'new': true }, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, to address your issue with updating only a few certain properties, you have to use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to set only a certain field. When you pass `userObj` directly to `findOneAndUpdate` you reset the whole object thus you have to pass all the existing properties. Use `$set`:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, { $set: userObj }, { upsert: true, new: true }, callback);
```

This will update only the properties defined in `userObj` to their new values and touch nothing else. Also, you could just use `findByIdAndUpdate` for this very use-case:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { $set: userObj }, { upsert: true, new: true }, callback);
```

Next, you shouldn't be using PUT. Use PATCH. PUT implies putting a resource at some URL, and replacing it entirely if it already exists. PATCH means you update only a few properties of a resource, and does replace the whole thing. This won't affect the app's functionality, but it's a huge semantics issue and end-user issue as they'd expect PATCH.

Comment: so there's no differences btw using $set and findByIdAndUpdate?

Comment: @JessieAnderson There is. Always use `$set` regardless if you use `findByIdAndUpdate` or `findOneAndUpdate` if you want to update only *just* one or more specific properties.

Comment: $set doesn't solve the problem. Tried it, I pass {name: undefined, age: 10}, the existing name is got overwrote.

Comment: @JessieAnderson Don't pass `name` if you don't want to update `name`. Only pass in properties you want to overwrite: `{ age: 10 }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id}, {$set: userObj}, /* ... */)
```