# How to update only some properties of object in MongoDB database with Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

This is basically the same question as this question... [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539709/how-to-update-only-some-properties-of-object-in-mongodb-database/50027079#50027079) ... but I need to know behavior around arrays.

I'm having issues with $set still updating other variables.This is my query and it's working to update these variables but it also sets a some arrays( media: [] and sports:[] ) I have in the athleteProfile.0 back to empty.

For clarity here's the Schema for the user object.

UserSchema.js

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
 password: { type: String, required: true },
 username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
 role: { type: String, required: true },
 athleteProfile: [AthleteSchema],
 evaluatorProfile: [EvaluatorSchema],
 adminProfile: [AdminSchema],
 search: [SearchSchema]
});
```

AthleteSchema.js

```
const AthleteSchema = new Schema({
 athEmail: String,
 firstName: {
   type: String,
   validate: {
     validator: (firstName) => firstName.length > 2,
     message: 'Name must be longer than 2 characters.'
   }
 },
 lastName: {
   type: String,
   validate: {
     validator: (lastName) => lastName.length > 2,
     message: 'Name must be longer than 2 characters.'
   }
 },
 profilePic: String,
 accountType: String,
 events: [{
   ref: 'Events',
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
 }],
 media: [MediaSchema],
 city: String,
 state: String,
 zip: Number,
 country: { type: String, uppercase: true },
 height: String,
 weight: Number,
 birthday: Date,
 sports: {
  type: [SportSchema],
   validate: [arrayLimit, '{PATH} exceeds the limit of 3']
 },
 references: {
   type: [ReferenceSchema],
   validate: [arrayLimit, '{PATH} exceeds the limit of 3']
 },
 evaluations: [EvaluationSchema],
 gradYear: Number,
 school: String
});
```

And then this is the request.

```
  User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, {
   $set:
  { username,
    password,
     'athleteProfile.0': {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      athEmail: email,
      gradYear,
      school,
      birthday,
      city,
      state,
      zip,
      weight,
      height
  }}
}, { returnNewDocument: true});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear that which field you want to update so what I understood is 
You can use the code :

```
User.findById(id, function (err, user) {

  if (err) return handleError(err);

  user.keytochange = newvalue;

  user.save(function (err, updatedUser) {


    if (err) return handleError(err);

    res.send(updatedUser);

  });
})
```

From the question i understood that you want to update the
`athleteProfile`  to 0 so change it accordingly

Editing the answer after the updated question 
So after seeing the question what you are tryimg to do is to update the atheleprofile base on the present user so I recommend you not to pass the who schema to the atheletprofile rather pass the objectid with ref to the user something like this

`title: String,
    Atheleprofile: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },`

 Now map it acordingly  so when you want to add the user give the objectId of the user to atheleprofile and then in update function 
Do it like this

User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);

```
  Atheleprofile.findById(user.id , (err,atheleprofile) => {
           Atheleprofile.fieldnam = newvalue;
          Athelerpofile.save((err,newAtheleprofileObejct) =>{
             console.log("done changes");
       }
     }



  });
}) `
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The athleteProfile is an array so that is why I used athleteProfile.0 to get into the first object and change that first object.

Comment: Ok so you want to update the first object of the atheleteprofile?

Comment: @ash i just updated the answer please go through that and if it is helpfull dont forget to give up vote

Comment: Thanks! That works. I tried to upvote but my reputation is too low. Hope it help you.

Comment: @ash If this answer helped you then you can mark this amswer with a tick mark to make it answered